# How can I create a file with executable permission itself?

Tags: shell, chmod

How can I create a file with executable permission itself? I want to create a new file with a single command with executable permissions how can I do it?

Comment: Why do you need it to be a single command? `touch` then `chmod`

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to create a new file with executable permissions is `touch newfile` then `chmod +x myfile`.

If your works require a lot of doing this task, I suggest using [alias](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146419/creating-an-alias-for-a-bash-script) to work more efficiently. Because **Bash alias doesn't directly accept parameters**, so you need to do a simple trick like that:

```
_xnew() { touch "$1" && chmod +x "$1"; }

alias xnew='_xnew'
```

To use it, you just need to type `xnew myfile` in your terminal:

```
$ user@host: xnew myfile

$ user@host: ls
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 400 Nov 10 08:00 myfile
```